# What do you put in child themes author tag?

Tags: author, child-theme, copyright

What is the common practice in authoring child themes ? I mean, if I make child theme of some free theme should I put myself as author or should I keep the name of the original themes author ? I searched quite a a bit but unfortunately couldn't find clear answer.

Comment: You can keep the ownership/copyright of your child theme but it would be great to provide credit to original theme author in your child theme. That's how child theme works. For example tons of developers sell/share child theme for `Genesis Framework` but they keep copyright of their own work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several scenarios:

1. If you had authored your child theme from scratch, using only your custom code then it is clearly **your** product.
2. If you had used code from parent theme in your child theme then it's **your derivative** of it, it's still yours but you **also** need to credit code used in line with its licensing requirements.
3. If you had taken third party child theme and modified it you usually choose between **keeping authorship and noting your modifications** (usually for private or semi–private use) or **renaming it** and treating it as derivative same as 2 (usually if you intend to distribute publicly).

In either case pay close attention to licensing requirements of original theme.